# What is a Document Base URL and Fallback Base URL?

Tags: html, url, document, radix, fallback

I would like to ask the community to help me understand what is a *Document Base URL* and *Fallback Base URL* **in terms of how they are defined in the HTML5's specification**. Please note I would prefer to expect a more understandable definition in terms of the definitions in the specification. However, individual perceptions are also welcome.

Link for [Document Base URL](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#document-base-url)'s definition.
Link for [Fallback Base URL](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#fallback-base-url)'s definition.

To me the definition for these two in the HTML5's specification kind of looks like having a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to understand recursion to understand recursion... ;) – These kinds of specifications are often self-referential. In the end they're very specific steps described in excruciating detail; they're essentially pseudo-code written in English as the programming language. You just need to follow them step by step to get to the result. One part referring to another term is like calling a function in code; they may even call each other, as long as there's no infinite loop in the end that's fine.

In this case it's not really that bad. The **fallback base URL** describes how to resolve a document's URL assuming cases where it may be a child of another document like an iframe, in which case it *falls back* to the parent's URL.

The **document base URL** resolves a document's URL taking `<base>` elements into account.

In summary, the specification is:

1. The **document base URL** is either the document's URL or the appropriately resolved `<base>` URL.
2. If the document is an `iframe`, take the parent's **document base URL** (see above).
3. Otherwise if it's `about:blank` but has a parent, take the parent's **document base URL** (see above). (This is a real niche case, but required for completeness.)
4. Otherwise it's the documents's address.

If the specification is henceforth talking about the **document base URL**, it just means step 1., the document's own URL, possibly resolved against `<base>`. If the specification is talking about the **fallback base URL**, follow all these steps.